# Class-level variable doesn't stay set

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, iis, repeater

I have a .net website I am working on which uses repeaters to build out several tables. As part of the Databind, I am adding keys to a class-level dictionary object so that later I can recall them and check if they have been changed. Below is my code:

```
public partial class pointsEdit : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public Dictionary<Int32, TextBox[]> PointsValues;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 clientID = 0;
        if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
        {
             if (Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out clientID) == true) {
                 //try
                 //{
                     if (!IsPostBack)
                     {
                         btnReturn.HRef = "clientEdit.aspx?id=" + clientID;

                         PointsValues = new Dictionary<int, TextBox[]>();
                         using (var db = new db())
                         {

                             var ev = db.activityPoints.Where(x => x.ClientID == clientID).ToArray();
                             tblEvent.DataSource = ev;
                             tblEvent.DataBind();

                         }


                     }
                 //}
                 //catch
                 //{

                 //}
             }
        }

    }


    protected void tblEvent_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

            using (var db = new db())
            {
                Int32 TypeKey;
                Int32 ActivityID;
                Int32.TryParse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem,"TypeKey").ToString(),out TypeKey);
                Int32.TryParse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ActivityID").ToString(), out ActivityID);

                var ev = db.events.Where(x => x.ID == TypeKey).First();
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblEvent")).Text = ev.name.ToString();
                ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tbPointValue")).Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "MaxPointsEach").ToString();
                ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tbMaxScored")).Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "MaxAttempts").ToString();

                PointsValues.Add(ActivityID, new TextBox[] { ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tbPointValue")), ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tbMaxScored")) });

            }
    }


   protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 ActivityID;
        TextBox[] TextBoxes;
        Int32 clientID = 0;
        Int32 ParseResult = 0;
        Int32 MaxPoints = 0;
        Int32 MaxAttempts = 0;
        Boolean NeedsUpdate = false;

          if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
          {
              if (Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out clientID) == true)
              {
                  //try
                 //{


                      using (var db = new db())
                      {
                          var s = db.activityPoints.Where(x => x.ClientID == clientID).ToArray();

                          for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                          {
                              ActivityID = s[i].ActivityID;
                              TextBoxes = PointsValues[ActivityID];
                          }
                      }

                  //} catch {

                  //}

                  }
              }


        }
 }
```

There is more code in the block which actually updates the values, but my loop only gets this far so I am removing that for simplicity's sake. When it gets to the "TextBoxes = PointsValues[ActivityID];" line of the submit method, it seems like the Dictionary object is no longer populated.

I have verified that there is an activity ID when it is added to the dictionary, and the count is correct for the number of objects that should have been added. At the Textboxes line, though, it tells me that "The given key was not present in the dictionary" and when I try to get a count, it gives the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. If I set the dictionary object to a new dictionary object just before that line, it allows me to get a count (of 0). It seems like the object is somehow being reset after being set up. Any ideas?

Comment: You are working with ASP.NET Web which means you would loose your object context once the request is processed. This would mean you dictionary would be lost. You should either save it in session of some sort to maintain it across requests.

Comment: This seems like it was my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help, have posted it as answer, please accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with ASP.NET Web which means you would loose your object context once the request is processed. This would mean you dictionary would be lost. You should either save it in session of some sort to maintain it across requests.

You can find details on how to implement session @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396